# Java Program Output (Stacks)

Tags: java, stack, push, stdout, stdin

This is my first question here on SO.
It might be a stupid question, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Consider the program Reader.java below:

```
   public class Reader {

      public static void main(String [ ] args) {

      Stack<String> stack = new Stack <String>();

         while (!StdIn.isEmpty ()) {

            stack.push(StdIn.readString());
         }

         while (!stack.isEmpty()) {

            StdOut.print(stack.pop() + " ");
         }
         StdOut.println();
     }
   }
```

Then it is given that a text file (words.txt) has the following contents:

```
read
cannot
I
```

Given that the program has compiled successfully using the files StdIn.java, StdOut.java and
Stack.java as used in the course, what output is produced by the following command line instruction?

```
java Reader < words.txt
```

The solution says that the output should be:

```
"I can read"
```

and not

```
"I cannot read"
```

Why is this?

Thanks :)

Comment: There must be some mistake in the textbook or we don't have all the details. Stacks are LIFO (last in, first out) so the output should be "I cannot read"

Comment: What are `StdIn` and `StdOut`?

Comment: StdIn and StdOut are just Princeton libraries for text input/output.

Comment: You don't have posted [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: This is actually a question from a previous exam paper, so I don't have the rest of the code. To my knowledge neither of the pop nor push methods should alter the output so that it produces "I can read".
Also, I'm still new here, so I'm getting used to how things work:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct output is what you got "I cannot read".  That should be a typo in that book.

What ever input is pushed in to the stack, will come out in reverse order during pop opertions (Not any new words)

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought. I have asked a few of my friends and they all agree that there is no way that the answer is "I can read."
However, this question comes from a previous exam paper, and it states that 1 mark is given for "I cannot read" and 2 marks for "I can read".

Comment: @EfVonZee Sometimes there can be mistakes on marking schemes and you have to use some common sense. Given the details provided here, there is no way the output could be "I can read". :)

Comment: Thanks :) I thought it was impossible... Just glad I'm not crazy.